# How to update Excel data? (Refresh all queries)

Tags: php, python, excel, powershell, ms-office

I have a Excel xlsm file with a few queries.

Currently I open it every day and click on the "Refresh All" command in the "Data" tab. I want this to be done automatically. I wrote a script in python (I'm a newbie in Python).

The problem is that after the data is refreshed and the Excel file has been saved, the refreshed data is not visible (I know that refreshing works because if I prevent to save and close the Excel file, the refreshed data is visible in the file )

The weird thing is that saving also works fine because when I try to modify cell B2 from 'config' it is changed...

Where is the problem?

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)

office = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = office.Workbooks.Open(r'\\server\CC_source.xlsm')

office.DisplayAlerts = True
office.Visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()

sh = wb.Worksheets("config")
sh.Cells(2,2).Value = wczoraj

wb.Close(True)
```

Maybe someone can recommend another script? For example, Powershell? PHP?
Or an other library for Python3?

Comment: If you want to write a script in `python`, why have you tagged this question `php`

Comment: @MarkBaker because if it is impossible with Python, maybe PHP could help...

Comment: Check Steves solution below as well if all else fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you requested another script to perform this action, I recommend PowerShell.  As a simple test, I created an Excel document, *SheetToRefresh.xlsx*, which has a data connection to a simple xml file. However, the script below will work for any data source that the Excel document is connected to. I have tested this on my own machine, the data refresh and save persists, as expected.

**RefreshExcel.ps1**

```
#Set the file path (can be a network location)
$filePath = "C:\Scripts\SheetToRefresh.xlsx"

#Create the Excel Object
$excelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

#Make Excel visible. Set to $false if you want this done in the background
$excelObj.Visible = $true

#Open the workbook
$workBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open($filePath)

#Focus on the top row of the "Data" worksheet
#Note: This is only for visibility, it does not affect the data refresh
$workSheet = $workBook.Sheets.Item("Data")
$workSheet.Select()

#Refresh all data in this workbook
$workBook.RefreshAll()

#Save any changes done by the refresh
$workBook.Save()

#Uncomment this line if you want Excel to close on its own
#$excelObj.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks!!! You saved a loooot of my time. Last one question... In this xls I have about 10 pivot tables. How to refresh them after refreshing workbook? Best option is to use some kind of loop...

Comment: Glad to help. I haven't worked much with pivot tables. However, I did a small test just now and I believe that `$workbook.RefreshAll()` should refresh _everything_ in the workbook. This appears to include pivot tables. You can test this out to see how it works for your scenario.

Comment: Yea, I've tested it. New - refreshed - data in pivot is not visible until I click on pivot and click on 'refresh' but this is not a problem. I can do this manually. My problem was with refreshing and You helped me. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

To refresh your query then your pivot, in Excel go to data> queries and connections> right click query for query properties> uncheck the enable background refresh.

Comment: Thanks Steve, this was breaking me nuts for ages