# I have a script that makes some manipulation with .xlsx file. How do i loop it with all files within folder?

Tags: powershell, loops

I have script that updates query in excel file

```
$filePath = "C:\Scripts\SheetToRefresh.xlsx"
$excelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excelObj.Visible = $true
$workBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open($filePath)
$workSheet = $workBook.Sheets.Item("Data")
$workSheet.Select()

$workBook.RefreshAll()

$workBook.Save()
```

Original script comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584911/how-to-update-excel-data-refresh-all-queries)

Now i need to loop it wihtin folder, i came up with:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\path" -Filter *.xlsx

foreach ($f in $files){
    
}
```

but struggling with changing filename for each file.(newbie with ps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down what needs to happen:

- Before:

  - Open Excel
  - Enumerate files
- During, for each file:

  - Open workbook
  - Run the relevant part of your existing script
  - Save and close workbook
- After:

  - Close Excel

So, let's start by moving the "Before" actions to the top of your new script:

```
# Open Excel
$excelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excelObj.Visible = $true

# Enumerate files
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\path" -Filter *.xlsx
```

Now we need to move the relevant parts of the existing script into the new loop. To get the full path of the file object returned by `Get-ChildItem`, use the [`FullName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname):

```
foreach($file in $files){
  # Open workbook from $file
  $workBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)

  # Refresh query results
  $workSheet = $workBook.Sheets.Item("Data")
  $workSheet.Select()
  $workBook.RefreshAll()

  # Save updated workbook to file
  $workBook.Save()

  # Close workbook
  $workBook.Close()
}
```

And finally we just need to quit Excel:

```
$excelObj.Quit()
```

Comment: However, after update script unchecks all my filters. Is it possible to save my filters in pivot table?