# automation filtering in pivot table(excel) with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a script that:

- opens excel file
- updates query to table
- updates pivot table
- closes excel

after data update all my filters in pivot table are lost.
so i need to select last 4 values in my column in table manualy.
is there way to specify filters in powershell?

original script comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68195989/i-have-a-script-that-makes-some-manipulation-with-xlsx-file-how-do-i-loop-it-w)